# MySQL Can't create table [errno: 150]

Tags: mysql, sql

Getting the above error on the following script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `incident`;

SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
CREATE TABLE `incident` (
  `incident_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `patient_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `history_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `incident_date` datetime default NULL,
  `incidentname_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `incident_type_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `pop_first_symptom` int(11) default NULL,
  `first_symptom_date` datetime default NULL,
  `similar_symptom_date` datetime default NULL,
  `first_consultation_date` datetime default NULL,
  `accident` int(1) default NULL,
  `accident_date` datetime default NULL,
  `pop_accident_state` int(11) default NULL,
  `pop_condition_related_to` int(11) default NULL,
  `flag_prothesis` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '0',
  `flag_initial_placement` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '0',
  `flag_orthodontics` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '0',
  `flag_occupational_illness` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '0',
  `box19` varchar(80) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `color` varchar(8) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default 'ffffff00',
  `referrals_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `referral_date` datetime default NULL,
  `facility_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `attorney_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `attorney_notes` text collate utf8_unicode_ci,
  `attorney_report_sent` date default NULL,
  `attorney_deposition_date` date default NULL,
  `attorney_trial_date` date default NULL,
  `attorney_notice_filing` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `attorney_final_settlement` date default NULL,
  `effective_date` datetime default NULL,
  `termination_date` datetime default NULL,
  `date` datetime default NULL,
  `pop_branch` int(11) default NULL,
  `pop_status` int(1) default NULL,
  `pop_eligibility` int(1) default NULL,
  `partial_begin_date` datetime default NULL,
  `partial_end_date` datetime default NULL,
  `last_work_date` datetime default NULL,
  `partial_return_to_work_date` datetime default NULL,
  `total_begin_date` datetime default NULL,
  `total_end_date` datetime default NULL,
  `last_xray_date` datetime default NULL,
  `last_seen_date` date default NULL,
  `assumed_date` datetime default NULL,
  `relinquished_date` datetime default NULL,
  `radiographs` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `oral_images` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `models` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `date_appliance_placed` date default NULL,
  `date_prior_placement` date default NULL,
  `paymentSourceCode` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `locatorCode` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `SAExceptionCode` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `flag_expanded` int(1) default NULL,
  `flag_archived` int(1) default NULL,
  `cda_reason_code` int(11) default NULL,
  `is_extraction` int(11) default '0',
  `extraction_tooth` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `initial_placement_date` date default NULL,
  `initial_placement_location` int(11) default '0',
  `prosthesis_material` int(11) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`incident_id`),
  KEY `patient_id_key` (`patient_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `incident_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`patient_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9854 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

Here is the patient table giving me the same error:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `patient`;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `patient_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `history_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `display_id` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `chart_num` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `bridge_num` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `provider_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `office_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `feeschedule_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `pop_marital_status` int(11) default NULL,
  `pop_employment` int(11) default NULL,
  `new_patient_date` date default NULL,
  `primary_ins_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `primary_ins_type` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `insured_id_number` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `flag_special_insurance` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci default '0',
  `flag_family_planning` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci default '0',
  `flag_epstd` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci default '0',
  `pop_relation_to_primary` int(11) default NULL,
  `pop_relation_to_secondary` int(11) default NULL,
  `pop_hipaa_release` int(11) default NULL,
  `hipaa_release_date` date default NULL,
  `patientNotes` text collate utf8_unicode_ci,
  `autoremind_notification_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ethnicity_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `patient_status` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created_by_module` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default 'P',
  `pop_patient_exception_code` int(11) default '0',
  `pop_native_language` int(11) default '0',
  `school_name` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `graduation_date` date default NULL,
  `hygienist_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `school_address_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`patient_id`),
  KEY `account_id_key` (`account_id`),
  KEY `person_id_key` (`person_id`),
  KEY `patient_status_index` (`patient_status`),
  KEY `person_id_index` (`person_id`),
  KEY `account_id_index` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `patient_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `patient_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9855 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

Comment: Wheres the DDL for `patient`?

Comment: 150 is usually related to a bad `FOREIGN KEY` definition, such as the data types of the column and its referenced column not matching _exactly_.  Or, the parent table `patient` has not yet been created.  Please post the `CREATE TABLE patient`

Comment: I guess you've omitted the "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" part of the error messages, haven't you?

Comment: Thanks! This SQL dump is HUGE, its nearly 3 gigs because the people who created it, uploaded all kinds of files to it. So what I did was break it down into smaller manageable scripts to run... after checking further from the above comments, it seems there is no 'patient' table, so it must've been missed somewhere along the lines!!! thanks so much for giving me the extra pair of eyes, thought I had it right haha.

Comment: Well, now I found the create patient statement, but its giving me the same error message.

Comment: @user2047549 You must create the `patient` table before `incident`....  And that table references `account`, so you must create the `account` table before `patient`.  `CONSTRAINT patient_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES account (account_id),`

Comment: @user2047549 Incidentally, when posting here, highlight your code and ctl-k or click the `{}` button to format it as a code block.

Comment: The account table is there, the dump has them all going in alphabetical order. There is no incident table right now because I cant create it... but I also cant create the patient table either. But I think its because its referencing the 'person' table.
REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`)

Comment: @user2047549 Yes I missed that one.  person and account must exist before you can create `patient`.

Comment: Yeah... I think Im seeing the issue here, for some reason the dump is in ABC order and there are references made to tables that havent been created yet... this is a pain! but I know what Ive got to do now... thank you!

Comment: Thanks again Michael! sometimes 4 eyes are better than one, I got the database restored finally. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your foreign key `patient_id` is not `NULL`. It must match to your referenced data type.

```
`patient_id` int(11) default NULL
```